# automatic xml documentation generation of decorators in python3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, doxygen, python-sphinx, pdoc

I am using decorators on classes in my python code.
I need to generate some xml which contains which classes have which decorators, which module they are in, and what are the globals in those modules.
I have tried all major documentation generators, but could not figure out even which is capable to do this.

- Doxygen (1.8.13-10): the generated documentation have no reference to any decorators
- Sphinx: I could not even get sphinx to generate any documentation on my modules. I have tried a couple of howtos, but automodule just does not seem to work.
- pydoctor: I was using this in python2 projects with a custom generator class, but does not work with python3
- pdoc works, but no decorators, and I do not see any way to generate xml
- pydoc3 just says there is no documentation found (as there are no comments, it is clean code)

A minimal example would contain the following tree:

```
src/categorizerai
src/categorizerai/__init__.py
src/categorizerai/ExampleService.py
```

Where `__init__.py` is empty, and `ExampleService.py` have the following code:

```
from winterboot.Autowired import Autowired

underlyingService = Autowired('underlyingService')

@Service
ExampleService(object):
    def serviceCall(foo: int = 0) -> int:
        return foo+1;
```

At the end I would create an xml like this (anything containing the necessary information is okay, I can xslt):

```
<project>
  <package name="categorizerai">
    <class type="Service" name="ExampleService"><!-- the type comes from the decorator -->
      <dependency name="underlyingService"/><!-- name of the global in the same module-->
    <method name="serviceCall" returns="int">
     <parameter name="foo" type="int" default="0"/>
    </method>
    </class>
  </package>
</project>
```

Comment: Regarding doxygen: which version of doxygen did you use? can you give a small example of the python code so we can try it.

Comment: I have updated the question with answers: 1.8.13-10 and https://github.com/kode-konveyor/CategorizerAI

Comment: Maybe you should try doxygen 1.8.15 (I don't know by head if there are changes regarding decorators).I was hinting to include a small piece of code in the question and not a complete repository that also changes in time.

Comment: What are the best practices to include example code when by the nature of the problem it will consists of multiple files, sometimes in multiple directories?

Comment: Well I think a basic example should be small and it should be possible to show a decorator problem with 1 or 2 small code snippets / files.

Comment: I have given a minimal example.